# Android: SQLiteDatabase cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy intentando hacer una base de datos para un juego usando libgdx, pero no hay manera de que me funcione. Aparece un error nada más empezar con el código: no encuentra nada relacionado con SQLite. El inicio del código es:

```
public class DBAndroid extends DBHighScore{
protected SQLiteOpenHelper db_connection;
protected SQLiteDatabase stmt;
```

Tanto SQLiteOpenHelper como SQLiteDatabase me aparecen en rojo, con el mensaje siguiente:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'SQLite...'

**Tampoco me aparece opción de instalar ninguna librería**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis archivos build.gradle son los siguientes (hay un total de 3):

**El de Project: NombreProyecto**

```
buildscript {


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'


}
```

}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

```
version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "CatchEmAll"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
```

}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

```
configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

}
```

}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

}
```

}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}

**El de module: android**

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
compileSdkVersion 27
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "borruey.catchemall"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

```
configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
    def outputDir = null
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
    if(outputDir != null) {
        copy {
            from zipTree(jar)
            into outputDir
            include "*.so"
        }
    }
}
```

}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

```
def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'borruey.catchemall.AndroidLauncher'
```

}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

```
jdt {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}

classpath {
    plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
    containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
}

project {
    name = appName + "-android"
    natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
    buildCommands.clear();
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
    buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
}
```

}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]

```
    iml {
        withXml {
            def node = it.asNode()
            def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
            builder.current = node;
            builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                    configuration {
                        option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**El de module: core**

```
apply plugin: "java"
```

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}

Simplemente aparece el error sin más, no me da opción a instalar imports ni nada de nada. ¿Cual puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar los siguientes `import` a tu clase para que reconozca las clases:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
```

ambas clases están contenidas en el Android SDK.

---

Cuando marquen en rojo las clases, puedes seleccionar y tecler la secuencía:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> y seleccionas la opción `Import class` para que agregue el `import` requerido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### **Actualización:**

El archivo build.gradle del proyecto debe tener la linea:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

de otra forma no reconocerá las clases del SDK.

Comment: Es lo primero que miré... pero nada, no aparece ningún import, es lo extraño. Acabo de poner una imagen en mi post principal mostrándolo.

Comment: Ya, me parece que no estas usando el Android SDK, estas usando Android Studio?

Comment: Si, es android studio. Hasta ahora no he tenido problemas, no lo acabo de entender... También he probado lo de Invalidate Caches / Restart y nada.

Comment: Agrega tu archivo build.gradle que se encuentra dentro de /app por favor , debes de tener al inicio apply plugin: 'com.android.application' @MarcusF

Comment: Editado! He añadido los 3 gradles que tengo.

Comment: @MarcusF en realidad tus archivos build.gradle tienen configuración de un proyecto de Eclipse o de IntelliJ Idea, falta agregar varias cosas para que sea un proyecto de android, te sugiero crear en Android Studio un nuevo proyecto y ahí agregar las clases.

Comment: ¿Ese podría ser el problema entonces? Me pondré con ello pues.

Comment: @MarcusF si de hecho es importantisimo usar: apply plugin: 'com.android.application' con esto indica usar el Android SDK, por esta razón no estas pudiendo agregar las clases del SDK.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a lo que comentas es **importar** las librerías, presiona las teclas **ALT + Intro** sobre la línea, como a continuación se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.